# How to NOT ignore hyphens in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I execute

`select strcmp('ATKINSHUBBARD', binary 'ATKINS-HUBBARD');`

I get a true (1) result.

How do get MySQL to recognize those as different strings and return a false result?

Using: MySql 5.6.15.56 (Percona). No, I do not have control over the updates.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for strcmp()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp)? A result of 1 means the strings are different. A result of 0 means the strings are the same.

Comment: Yeah... now I look like an end user. Next I should remember my own advice and RTFM. Thanks Bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you're confusing how `STRCMP()` function works in MySQL. `STRCMP()`returns 0 if the strings are the same. Check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp).

Comment: Yup. I'm a dummie and didn't RTFM. Thanks.